# Chrome extension: get current site name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just get started building my first Chrome extension. One functionality in my app is to get the name of the current site. For example, if the current url matches "*://*.facebook.com/", I would interpret this url and know the site name as Facebook.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to do so in a content script ?

Comment: Any way will do, although I think it's impossible to do it in a content script (since we don't have access to chrome.tabs there). What I'm thinking of doing is to send a message to the background and get back the solution.

Comment: I think it should work if you try to access `window.location.host` from the content script, since the script is injected to that page

Comment: Yup it works. Great yet simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: @OmriAharon Please make that into an answer. Avoid answering in comments - it cannot be marked as accepted, makes a bad question "track record" for the OP, and it's not obvious that the question is answered.

Comment: @user3284573 Like Xan said, please accept the answer for future thread visitors to know what solved your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the content script is injected into the page, you could use `window.location.host` in the content script itself and get the name of your site.

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear wheter you want to get the host name or the title of the page, but you can get both of them if you want.

**Inside a content script** you can do:

```
var site = location.hostname,
    title = document.title;

alert("Site: " + site + " - Title: " + title);
```

If you want to do this **from the background page** and you don't want to use content scripts nor inject code in the tab then you can only get the host name:

```
var site;

chrome.tabs.query({/* some query */}, function(tabs) {
    site = tabs[0].url.split("/")[2];
    alert("Site: " + site);
});
```

If you also want to **get the page title from the background page** you'll need to use `executeScript()`. **NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

```
var title;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sensResponse) {
    if (message.title) {
        title = message.title;
        alert("Title: " + title);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.query({/* some query */}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: "chrome.runtime.sendMessage({title: document.title});"});
});
```

---

For more informations about the methods I used in the above snippets you can see these documentation links:

- [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)

  - [`chrome.tabs.query` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)
  - [`chrome.tabs.executeScript` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) (deprecated, manifest v2)
- [`chrome.scripting.executeScript` method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) (manifes v3)
- [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

  - [`chrome.runtime.onMessage` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)
  - [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)